# Trigger in template causes wrong rendering

Tags: wpf, triggers, custom-controls, selector, contentcontrol

I'm implementing my own fake `TabControl` to look like IE8-tabs (I'm aware of other implementations of tabcontrol).

My `TabControl` derives from `Selector`, and my `TabItem`s derive from `ContentControl`.
When a tab is selected I set `IsSelected` (a dependencyproperty) to true.
My `Trigger` looks like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
</Trigger>
```

The default margin for my `TabItem` is 0,2,0,0. In other words, unselected `TabItem`s should have a slight offset to the selected.
I've tried doing this in reverse, and using height instead. The result is that `TabItem`s that are selected seems to be clipped instead of altering the margin.
I get the correct visual when the property is set on the tag directly, i.e.:

```
<local:TabItem IsSelected="true"/>
```

I've tried invalidating `Arrange`, `Visual` and `Measure` in my `IsSelected` dependency property without much success.

What am I missing here?

Edit:

Here's the complete style for the `TabItem` (the style is partly based on this project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfTabControl.aspx):

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=TabItemNormalBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TabItem}">
                <Border CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItemOuterBorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
                    <Border CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItemInnerBorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            <Button x:Name="PART_CloseButton" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="5,0,5,0"
                            Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            />
                        </Grid>

                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=TabItemSelectedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is really hard to answer without seeing the entire layout code in XAML.

Comment: I've added the TabItem above. I hope that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I stored the tabitems desiredsize in MeasureOverride, and forgot to clear them in subsequent calls.